# Numbers of figure references

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, numbering, subfloats

I use enumerating of figures within the section

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
```

however, when I use a reference to subfigure, instead of 1.1 (a) I get 1(a). How should I fix it?

Working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}

\renewcommand{\section}{%
    \@startsection
        {section}{1}{0mm}
    {\baselineskip}
    {\baselineskip}
     {\fontsize{14}{14}\centering\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%       
   }
   \makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{a}
    \begin{figure}[h] \label{fig:1} \centering
        \subfigure[]{\label{fig:11}
            \includegraphics[width=60mm]{1.png}}%
        \subfigure[]{\label{fig:12}
            \includegraphics[width=60mm]{2.png}}

        \caption{11 and 12}.
    \end{figure}
    \section{b}
        \ref{fig:11}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using the obsolete `subfigure` package you should use [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption); here's your code using `subfig`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{%
    \@startsection
        {section}{1}{0mm}
    {\baselineskip}
    {\baselineskip}
     {\fontsize{14}{14}\centering\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%       
   }
%subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
    \@startsection
    {subsection}{1}{0mm}
   {\baselineskip}
   {\baselineskip}
   {\fontsize{14}{14}\centering\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%
   }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{a}
\begin{figure}[h] 
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:11}%
  \includegraphics[width=60mm]{1.png}}\ %
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:12}%
  \includegraphics[width=60mm]{2.png}}
\caption{11 and 12}
\label{fig:1} 
\end{figure}

\ref{fig:11} or \ref{fig:1}\subref{fig:11}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, your redefinition for `\thefigure` won't reset the counter when a new section begins; if you want to reset the counter you could use

```
\@addtoreset{figure}{section}
```

inside `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`, or

```
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
```

from the `amsmath` package, or

```
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
```

from the `chngcntr` package. Also note that, inside floating environments, `\label` must always appear *after* `\caption` (in your code `\label` is before `\caption`).

If, for some reason you need to stick to the subfigure package, then you can redefine `\thesubfigure`, `\p@subfigure`, and `\@thesubfigure`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure(\alph{subfigure})}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{}
\renewcommand{\@thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})\hskip\subfiglabelskip}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{%
    \@startsection
        {section}{1}{0mm}
    {\baselineskip}
    {\baselineskip}
     {\fontsize{14}{14}\centering\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%       
   }
%subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
    \@startsection
    {subsection}{1}{0mm}
   {\baselineskip}
   {\baselineskip}
   {\fontsize{14}{14}\centering\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%
   }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{a}
\begin{figure}[h] 
\centering
\subfigure[]{\label{fig:11}%
  \includegraphics[width=60mm]{1.png}}\ %
\subfigure[]{\label{fig:12}%
  \includegraphics[width=60mm]{2.png}}
\caption{11 and 12}
\label{fig:1} 
\end{figure}

\ref{fig:11}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot use \numberwithin because of extra dot which appears with section. With this example I cannot use \setlength{\subfigtopskip}{1cm}, how should I change it?

Comment: @Pavasaris yes, `\subfigtopskip` is not defined in `subfig` nor in `subcaption`; but do you really want to add `1cm` before the subfigures?

Comment: I need 1cm between subfigures. And when I was prepering my report, it was defined like this, so now the view got broken and there will be so much work to repair it :(

Comment: @Pavasaris I can't think of a quick fix now... anyways, it seems as if your best option for this document is to continue using `subfigure`; in my updated answer I've provided the necessary code with `subfigure`. However, for future documents, I recommend switching to either `subfig` or `subcaption`.

Comment: Thanks! I will know it for the next time, but maybe could you tell me what is the disatvantage of using subfigures? It's because of more difficult defining of true references?

Comment: @Pavasaris no, the reason is more fundamental: `subfigure` is incompatible with really important packages such as `hyperref` and `caption`.