# Subfigure numeration inside the section

Tags: numbering, subfloats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Numbers of figure references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58690/numbers-of-figure-references)

I'm having some problem about subfigure numeration.
The figures in my work are numbered inside the section using the line 
`\numberwithin{figure}{section}`, so they are like figure 2.1, 2.2, 2.3...

I tried to use the subfigure command and make reference to that figure, so the numeration should be 2.1(a), but it ignores the section number, showing just "figure 1(a)".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subfigure[subfigure a]{\includegraphics{image1} \label{image1}}
\subfigure[subfigure b]{\includegraphics{image2} \label{image2}}
\end{figure}

According to figure \ref{image1} we ...
\end{document}
```

Is that a way I could use this kind of numeration and the subfigure command?

If I remove the line `\numberwithin{figure}{section}` the numeration is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by redefining the command `\thesubfigure` and a couple of others. Take a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58690/12092) for the details (read the whole thing). Incidentally, that answer recommends switching to a newer package that does the same thing.

Your question is basically a duplicate of that one. (You don't need to redefine `\section` and `\subsection`, as the sample code shows; that's all irrelevant to the question).

Comment: You are completely right. I could solve the problem using the `\ref{fig}\subref{subfig}` command.

Comment: See also [subcaption vs. subfig: Best package for referencing a subfigure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13625)

Comment: Note that links to other answers do not qualify as new answers. If this question is solved by an answer of a similar question it is a duplicate and should be closed as such instead.

Comment: Go ahead and close it then. As you see there was some irrelevant fluff in the original answer that I wanted to highlight, and anyway I don't have enough privileges to vote to close.