# Subfig Error while using Tikz

Tags: subfloats

I was reading this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58696) and encountered an error while trying to compile the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:fig1a}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}\
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:fig1b}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\draw[->,very thick] (0,0) -- (1.9,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have tried to edit parts of the code, and it seems that the root of the problem is that an '>' in the tikz code ends the subfloat enviroment. It's there a way to fix this?

Comment: There seems to be a connection to `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`. As an alternative to `subfig` you might be interested in using the `subcaption` package.

Comment: Use `\shorthandoff{<>}` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Possibly related (duplicate?): [Tikz default arrow style and babel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304137/134144)

Comment: What is the difference between `subfig` and `subcaption`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @leandriis stated in his comment, your question is related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304164/31034) and the solution is there. For addditional solution is to use of `\shorthandoff{<>}` for Spanish babel when using `figure` environment. That is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{<>} %<-------------Add-------------
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:fig1a}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}\
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:fig1b}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\draw[-latex,very thick] (0,0) -- (1.9,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what `\shorthandoff{<>}` does?

Comment: The problem is that the `spanish` module for `babel` makes `>` and `<` active characters for its special management of Spanish quotations. Please look at this answer for detailed answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163955/31034