# Tikz Shorten key Error in Subfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfig

I'm drawing this figure

[image]

And specifically, in the red line `X1-P` I used the key `shorten` and I need to put in `subfigure`, as follows

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{tikz, pgf, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{babel, calc, through, intersections}

\title{Problema 3.4-11}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\textbf{3.4-11}] Problema...

\begin{proof}
Sea $K$ la circunferencia variable y $O$ su centro (figura \ref{ej-11})...

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subfigure[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, font = \small]

\node[] (O1) at (-4,0) {};
\node[] (O2) at (2,0) {};
\node[] (O) at (0,4) {};
\node[] (T) at (0,0) {};
\node[] (X1) at (-4,4) {};
\node[] (X2) at (3.2,1.6) {};
\node[] (P) at (8,0) {};

\draw[dashed, thin, gray] (0,-5) -- (0,9);
\draw[thin] (-9,0) -- (9,0);

\node (S1) at (O1) [draw, circle through = (T), cyan!75!black] {};
\node (S2) at (O2) [draw, circle through = (T), green!75!black] {};
\node (S) at (O) [draw, circle through = (T), orange] {};

\draw[red, thick, shorten >= -30pt, shorten <= -30pt] (X1) -- (P); %ERROR!

\fill (O1) circle (0.5mm);
\fill (O2) circle (0.5mm);
\fill (O) circle (0.5mm);
\fill (T) circle (0.5mm);
\fill (X1) circle (1mm);
\fill (X2) circle (1mm);
\fill[red] (P) circle (1.5mm);

\node[below left] at (P) {$P$};
\node[left] at (X1) {$X_{1}$};
\node[right] at (X2) {$X_{2}$};
\node[below] at (O1) {$O_{1}$};
\node[below] at (O2) {$O_{2}$};
\node[below] at (T) {$T$};
\node[right] at (O) {$O$};

\node[below] at (-7,-3) {$K_{1}$};
\node[below] at (3,-2) {$K_{2}$};
\node[above] at (3,7) {$K$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\label{sub:recta}
}
\caption{}
\label{ej-11}
\end{figure}
\end{proof}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But this yields an error and I realized when I delete the shorten key, error disappear

What is happen?

PS. Ok, I know I can "cheat" and use auxiliary points to extend my line, but I need know the reason for this error too

I apologize for possible misspellings

Comment: The `subfigure` package is deprecated. Please consider switching to `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.

Comment: @leandriis Ok, I'm gonna try

Comment: `shorten` by negative distances leads to paths that are not fully contained in the bounding box. That is, the length you add by supplying `shorten` with some negative distance will not be taken into account in the bounding box determination.

Comment: The error, however, has nothing to do with shorten. It comes from the `<` and `>` characters. Just adding `>=latex` yields the same error.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I see, doesn't it matter that I add the Tikz `babel` library?

Comment: It suffices to say `\begingroup\shorthandoff{>}\shorthandoff{<}` after `\centering` and add `\endgroup` before `\end{figure}`. It seems to be a strange interaction between `subfigure` and `babel`. So you should do what @leandriis and will be fine, I think.

Comment: I confirm: if you use `subcaption` the `babel` library is sufficient. In your document you could use `\shorthandoff{>}\shorthandoff{<}`, but `subcaption` is probably a better choice, i.e. this issue adds to the reasons why one should no longer use `subfigure`.

Comment: Thank you both for your contributions! It wroks!

Comment: This question seems to be related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/478296/194703), *maybe* a duplicate. The upshot seems to be that `subcaption` works without additional efforts, but `subfigure` and `subfig` do not.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this may be helpful for others, here is a community wiki summary of the comments. The issue does not have anything to do with shorten specifically. It is because you use `<` and `>` together with

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

Under normal circumstances one would think that

```
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
```

takes care of that. This is however not the case for your original document, which uses the `subfigure` package. If you keep using the package, you can add `\begingroup\shorthandoff{><}` after `\centering`, and `\endgroup` before `\end{figure}`. However, there is an arguably much better way: [use the `subcaption` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546171/tikz-shorten-key-error-in-subfigure#comment1379738_546171). ([This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/478296/194703) suggests that with the `subfig` package the problem persists.) Then indeed the problem gets solved by loading the `babel` library.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,through}

\title{Problema 3.4-11}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\textbf{3.4-11}] Problema...

\begin{proof}
Sea $K$ la circunferencia variable y $O$ su centro (figura \ref{ej-11})...

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, font = \small,>=latex]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, font = \small,>=latex]

\node[] (O1) at (-4,0) {};
\node[] (O2) at (2,0) {};
\node[] (O) at (0,4) {};
\node[] (T) at (0,0) {};
\node[] (X1) at (-4,4) {};
\node[] (X2) at (3.2,1.6) {};
\node[] (P) at (8,0) {};

\draw[dashed, thin, gray] (0,-5) -- (0,9);
\draw[thin] (-9,0) -- (9,0);

\node (S1) at (O1) [draw, circle through = (T), cyan!75!black] {};
\node (S2) at (O2) [draw, circle through = (T), green!75!black] {};
\node (S) at (O) [draw, circle through = (T), orange] {};

\draw[red, thick, shorten >= -30pt, shorten <= -30pt] (X1) -- (P);
%coordinate[sloped,pos=1,xshift=30pt](P') (P'); 

\fill (O1) circle [radius=0.5mm];
\fill (O2) circle [radius=0.5mm];
\fill (O) circle [radius=0.5mm];
\fill (T) circle [radius=0.5mm];
\fill (X1) circle [radius=1mm];
\fill (X2) circle [radius=1mm];
\fill[red] (P) circle [radius=1.5mm];

\node[below left] at (P) {$P$};
\node[left] at (X1) {$X_{1}$};
\node[right] at (X2) {$X_{2}$};
\node[below] at (O1) {$O_{1}$};
\node[below] at (O2) {$O_{2}$};
\node[below] at (T) {$T$};
\node[right] at (O) {$O$};

\node[below] at (-7,-3) {$K_{1}$};
\node[below] at (3,-2) {$K_{2}$};
\node[above] at (3,7) {$K$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\label{sub:recta}
\caption{A subfigure.}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure.}
\label{ej-11}
\end{figure}
\end{proof}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here are some additional off-topic comments:

1. If you shorten a path by a negative length, you make it longer, and the additional part won't be taken into account for the bounding box. In the case at hand this is not a problem.
2. If you use the `circle` syntax, consider using `circle[radius=...]` instead of `circle(...)`. In this case you could simplify your code by making the circles nodes. If you do that, all these `\node[right]...` could become labels. This would make the picture more appealing because the size of the circles will be taken into account.